# Sharepoint 2013 onpremise migration to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

.        I need some advice.I would like to migrate a site collection to SharePoint online.I know i have options like shaeegate or metalogix but not all clients have these tools and money.
Can i use powershell? Its not a big site.
Any tips or ideas shared would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Since it's not a big site, [metalogix trial](http://pages.metalogix.com/trial-content-matrix.html) allows you to migrate max 10GB for free.

Comment: Hi Sergei, Thanks for the tip.About the content migration express? Is this stil available?

Comment: Sorry what is migration express?

Comment: Sergei its the same as Metalogix (content matrix)

Answer (score 3):

Introduction
Use PowerShell migration Azure APIs [[ARTICLE]](https://migrationspo.blogspot.com/2016/06/sharepoint-migration-to-online-spo-o365_20.html).
This involves the script which is helpful in creating SPO Migration Package from SharePoint Onprem Content using PowerShell Commands i.e. exporting the lists, document libraries, form libraries etc. of a site collection or a site.
Business case
Azure APIs are provided by Microsoft. These APIs can be used to save the overall licensing cost of migration tool. Effective Time utilization as well as Work fragmentation by using this API.

Targeted Audience

- SharePoint Application Developers
- SharePoint Administrator
- SharePoint Architect

Technologies used

- SharePoint onprem (SP2010/SP2013/MOSS-2007)
- SharePoint Online (Office 365)
- Online management PowerShell
- Azure storage, blobs & containers
- Require as access to Azure Management tool for creation of the Azure Blob’s

Pre-requisites
RDP to a WFE for SharePoint Onprem Server
Valid Office 365 subscription
Valid Microsoft Azure subscription
SharePoint Online management shell version 16.0.4017.1200 or above version. Download here More details at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx
windows PowerShell 3.0 and above version
SharePoint Admin Tenant account access is required.

Migration Steps for SharePoint Online (O365–SPO) from SharePoint Onprem

To keep things simple, let’s divide the entire process in few steps:
For migrating the content from SharePoint On-Premise to SharePoint Online includes five steps as below.

1. Create SPO Migration Package from SharePoint On-Prem Content.
2. Prepare Final SPO Migration Package.
3. Upload SPO Migration Package to Azure Blob Containers.

   4. Submit Migration Job.
   5. Check Migration Job Status (Optional).

Answer (score 1):

The most optimistic answer for the question is Yes. But it all depends up on the analysis and after gathering the basic details on the inventory of the on-premise site collection

Such as :

- number of lists, document libraries (also, versions - if yes its gonna be really complex and time consuming)
- Customization's
- Page layouts
- Permissions and with granular item level permissions if any
- no.of sub sites 
  Content size

Overall there are two preferred API support which are **CSOM/Powershell based CSOM** and Rest based services. CSOM is the most suitable but even it has certain limitations.

If you have complex customizations and granular permissions then it will be very tedious to do this kind of script based migration.

Overall, you might end up writing the custom solution/scripts but those are not really a fault tolerant/proof when compared to a tool based approach.

So better you weigh these options and decide based on the available time, resources and complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Well Usually there are 3 ways that you can go about migration

1) manually - but this is terible solution, noone should ever even consider it.

2) Hybrid - which is good, for a transition period but essentially a cheat, since you don't move sites. Actually this method is also used if you imnvest heavily in SharePoint server customization, but I guess taht in your case this is not the case.

3) 3rd party tool like sharegate. Which is actually the only logycal option.

If you do indeed have heavy customizations on the server side, I would advise contacting some organization that can assis you in migrating your SharePoint, especially if we are talking about corporate environmnt here. Might I suggest Digital Design, here is a link http://www.digdes.com/services/sharepoint-to-office-365-migration . I pesonally was quite pleased with there services.